# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a 2 dimensional array that is fairly large and I keep getting the error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".  I've tried the -Xmx command and I still get it.

Could there be an alternative I could use to 2D arrays?  Or a way to increase heap size that works.

Comment: How big is your array and what heap sizes are you using?  What type is being stored in the array?

Comment: Integers are being stored, size is around [20000][20000].

Comment: You are aware that an `int[20000][20000]` array takes up 1,600,000,000 bytes (~1.5 GiB) of RAM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If not all elements of the matrix are occupied (or even share a very common default value), you can use a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).

One of the simplest methods for doing this is using a HashMap:

```
Map<Point, Integer> matrix = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();

matrix.put(new Point(5, 2), 7);
Integer fiveTwo = matrix.get(new Point(5, 2));
```

You can iterate over all indices like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < COL_COUNT; j++ ) { 
       Integer val = matrix.get(new Point(i, j));
       //val is null here if not stored in the matrix.  Replace with a different
       //default as desired.  eg:
       //if ( val == null ) val = 0;
       process(val);
    }
}
```

Iterating over only *occupied* indices is also easily possible:

```
for ( Entry<Point, Integer> entry : matrix ) {
    process(entry.getValue());
}
```

Though this may return some cells that have been explicitly set to the default.  What is more difficult with this implementation is iterating over only occupied indices in a specific order.

This is an example of a "dictionary of keys" implementation as described in the Wikipedia article linked above.

Comment: This looks promising, I will give this a try.  Is there a way I can loop through the whole matrix using this method?

Comment: This implementation is less efficient in that regard, but it's still possible.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: No problem!  You might want to take a look around the interwebs to see if there's a nice library to give you a performant implementation of a sparse matrix.  This was just meant as an easy to understand implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to make allocation of your objects less expensive. As Jon Skeet (*Tips hat*) is getting at, it really depends on how big the array is, and what's in it. Flyweight can buy you a lot sometimes, but only so much.